# Using an array of strings to stop regex expression

Tags: arrays, regex, string, powershell

I'm trying to split up an emails subject line with pairs and then store that in hash table then I will then use to send it out to a different program.

```
$message = "WHERE=bmc3423 ENVIRONMENT=WINDOWS WHO=DDD WHAT=CPU WHATVAR=PERCENTAGE WHATVAL=98 WHY=HAPPY WHEN=02/05/2015 4:34 pm SEVERITY=WARNING PRIORITY=5 STATUS=OPEN TYPE=Stuff CI=bmc3232 MNEMONIC=DAW MESSAGE=happy days are here for email"

$tokens = "what","whatvar","whatval","where","when","severity","status","type","CI","mnemonic","who","message"

$tokenhash = @{}
ForEach($item in $tokens)
{
    #$item
    $match= $message -match  "$item=([\S\s]*)\S*=?"
    $tokenhash.Add($item,"$Matches")
    out-host -InputObject $Matches.1
}
```

I was not sure if there was a way to use the token list in the regex so that is checks each token word to make sure it stops collecting at any of the tokens

Example:

```
$match= $message -match  "$item=([\S\s]*)where="
$match= $message -match  "$item=([\S\s]*)when="
```

I hope I explained that ok.  I'm a horrible communicator.  Right now I"m trying to use \S*=? to try to get whatever the next starting of the pair would be.  They may not be in the same order when coming in.

Comment: Well, I found a work around.  Not sure why I cannot press enter  for a character return for this box.       $match= $message -match  "$item=([\S\s]*?)(?:WHERE|ENVIRONMENT|WHO|WHAT|WHATVAR|WHATVAL|WHY|WHEN|SEVERITY|PRIORITY|STATUS|TYPE|CI|MNEMONIC|MESSAGE)=?"

Answer (score 0):

If the key is always just a single word, you could do with two simple statements and a for loop:

```
# Split into alternating groups of key/value
$tokens = $message -split '([\S]*)=' |Where-Object { $_ }

# Populate dictionary:
for($i = 0; $i -lt $tokens.Count; $i += 2){
    $tokenhash[$tokens[$i]] = $tokens[$i+1]
}
```

Comment: `$message -split '\s+(?=\S+?=)' | ConvertFrom-StringData` outputs a hashtable in one op (PS3+).